# How to have a group stroke with clipping mask applied?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, mask

I tried to use the offset path on appearance panel as taught in [this video](https://youtu.be/1yjvCIsxC-A?t=316)
which is great, but i know if i have clipping mask, it cant be stroked. Whats the workaround on this workflow?

As shown in my example. A star is masked inside the cup, thus the group doesn't stroke the cup, i also have other things in the group.

I'm looking for flexibility to **''draw inside/mask''** & also moving around objects while maintaining that **keyline/outer stroke.**

[image]
If not possible, what are the other efficient workflows? thanks!

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of "draw inside" due to this.

In my experience, for optimum results Clipping masks should *never* have a fill or stroke assigned to them.

Draw inside will often assign a fill to the clipping mask. This creates a unnecessarily complex shape that may cause issues upon output. That is *not* to say that it *will* cause issues, but it **can**. So, I prefer to head such issues off during construction where possible.

The simplest solution is to *not* use the "draw inside" feature. If you need something masked, merely copy the underlying shape, in this case the cup, and then paste in front and create a clipping mask. Then group things.

So I would...

1. Copy the cup shape
2. Deselect all
3. `Edit > Paste in Front`
4. Select the star and duplicate cup shape
5. `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`
6. Group the mask with the original cup shape

You can then apply a stroke to this *group* without any issue.

[image]

---

You can also reverse engineer this quite easily if the "draw inside" mask is already in place.

- Use the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) to select *only* the clipping mask shape
- Set the Fill and Stroke to `None`
- `Edit > Copy`
- Deselect all
- `Edit > Paste in Back`
- `Object > Clipping Mask > Release`
- Set the fill to the correct color
- Select it all an `Object > Group`

Comment: @Momori06 Please post a new question if you have a new question. It's not a good idea to overload the question area with multiple questions. It helps future visitors find things if the question area is limited to a single question.

Comment: ok, here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150358/how-to-quicly-apply-changes-from-the-original-layer-shape-to-the-clipping-mask